# How can I access the objects in a vector of class objects in C++?

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a vector called DriverVect that is a member of class Drivers. DriverVect is a vector of class Driver objects (not Drivers). I am a beginner programmer and I am trying to access and modify the elements in DriverVect from my main function.

Edit: minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Driver {
  public:
    void SetID(int DriverID);
  int GetID() const;

  private:
    int ID;
};

class Drivers {
  public:
    vector < Driver > DriverVect;
};

int main() {
  Drivers d;
  cout << DriverVect.at(1) << endl;
}
```

Comment: So, you have `class Drivers { std::vector<Driver> DriverVect; };`? Show us the code.

Comment: [Start with this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8f1651bc7837cc6).  Modify that code so that you can post a [mcve] that shows the issue.

Comment: Here is my complete Drivers class:   class Drivers {
public:
vector<Driver> DriverVect;
void AddDriver();
void EditDriver();
void DeleteDriver();

};

Comment: @absoluteBeginner -- Take the code I had at the link, add to it, remove code from it, and reproduce the error that way.  The code I have compiles without issue, so the request is for you to take the working code, and break it so that you can post that broken code here for us to diagnose.  Either that, or learn from that code what your mistake was and resolve the issue yourself.

Comment: @absoluteBeginner And put the resulting [mcve] in your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61217554/edit) the question. Don't put it as a comment. Read the link about "_minimal reproducible example_". Your current code isn't that.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I don't see the reason of having both `Driver` and `Drivers`: this would usually be done with some some data structure, not a whole new class. Also, you should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You mentioned that you are trying to access the vector but didn't mention how, or what error you are getting. If `DriverVect` is public, you can access its elements with the subscript operator `[]`. Of course you can't access an index out of range, so it must be properly resized/initialized beforehand.

Comment: It seems like your `DriverVect` is `public`. The only problem is that you try to access it without `d`. Try `Driver& driver = d.DriverVect.at(1);` (after you've added two `Driver`s) and you'll have a reference to the second `Driver`. To print it like you try, you must add an overload for `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Driver&);`

Comment: Bang-a-rang! That we can work with

Answer (score -1):

For modifying the elements of a vector, you need to access them by reference using

```
auto &element = vector[i];
```

Then `element` is tied to the element in the vector, in the same way, storing a pointer would work.

Comment: Guess proven incorrect once the asker provided an answerable question.